# Highcharts - Logarithmic chart - Y axis grid line shows in the middle of the graph for data set with narrow range

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Using Highcharts, when data on the logarithmic y axis is in a narrow range the y-axis 'major' grid line shows up in the middle of the graph with a label of 316.227...
For example, 
series: [{
        data: [152, 235, 231, 278, 292, 312, 346, 414, 522, 579],
Most of the data sets are not like this and we would like to use startOnTick: false and endOnTick: false to maximize the data on the graph for all cases. 
Is there any way to have the major grid line not show up in the case where the data range is contained within 1 log cycle/decade?
https://jsfiddle.net/sartzberger/594Lu6y3/

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {

    title: {
        text: 'Logarithmic axis demo'
    },

    xAxis: {
        tickInterval: 1,
        type: 'linear',
        visible: false,
        accessibility: {
            rangeDescription: 'Range: 1 to 10'
        }
    },

    yAxis: {
        type: 'logarithmic',
        minorTickInterval: 0.1,
        minTickInterval: 1,
        startOnTick: false,
        endOnTick: false,
        labels: {
            enabled: true
        },
        accessibility: {
            rangeDescription: 'Range: 0.1 to 1000'
        }
    },

    tooltip: {
        headerFormat: '<b>{series.name}</b><br />',
        pointFormat: 'x = {point.x}, y = {point.y}'
    },

    series: [{
        data: [152, 235, 231, 278, 292, 312, 346, 414, 522, 579],
        pointStart: 1
    }]
});
```

Comment: `Is there any way to have the major grid line not show up in the case where the data range is contained within 1 log cycle/decade?` Could you explain more precisely when the minor grid line should not show up? If you are able to reproduce this case and provide some data when you want to hide it, it will be perfect. There is a simplified demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ukp5fjaz/

Comment: The dark line in your demo (and mine) should be the weight used for a ;major' decade/cycle line. Given that in these demos the data is contained within a single log cycle there shouldn't be any 'major' line. The demo shows the lighter 'minor' lines in the correct position. The line styled with the CSS .highcharts-grid-line is arbitrarily positioned in the middle of the graph.

Comment: As I understood - something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/yL9kc5v0/ ?

Comment: Sort of. That gets rid of the major axis but we need to see all of the minor grid lines. In our use case we don't show the y-axis values and the algorithm that omits minor grid lines causes confusion/complaints from our customers.

Comment: Hm, maybe setting the `minorTickInterval` to 'auto' fit to your requirements? https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/3ymt6b7j/

Comment: No, that's worse. The lines at 200, 400, 600 are now styled darker than the lines in between those values and there is also a set of double lines below 200. Also, having 8 increments between 200 and 400 or between 400 and 600 isn't a typical representation of what a log scale looks like. In this exact data example I'd be looking for lines only at 200, 300, 400, 500, 600 which are all styled the same.

Comment: Oh, thanks for a detailed explanation of what do you expect. You should be able to achieve it by setting wanted tickAmount to show: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/fd953ejr/

Comment: Thanks! We'll see how to incorporate this!